# NASA SRTM: precipitous contour lines in TileMill

Tags: gdal, tilemill, srtm, terrain

I was trying to make a nice looking print map of Bali (Indonesia) in TileMill. After creating a terrain layer (using [this walkthrough](http://steveko.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/terrain-in-tilemill-a-walkthrough-for-non-gis-types/)) I noticed that the island's coastline was precipitous.

[image: precipitous coastline in TileMill, Kuta Beach]

Is this caused by GDAL or wrong input data from [CIGAR](http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/inputCoord.asp)? I believe it can't be fixed within TileMill as the hillshading layer seems also affected.

**Edit**: With a bit CartoCSS the contour lines can easily be hidden. But not the slope scale image...

[image: faulty slope scale, Southern Bali]

---

TileMill 0.10.1 (v0.10.1-134-g31027ed, Windows)
GDAL: OSGeo4W on Win 32bit

Answer (score 1):

The resolution of the base countries layer is too low so the SRTM and the lo-res shapefile from TileMill don't line up.

Use a higher resolution shorelines file for higher zooms.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include what that means and how to do it?